# How to get the data only from the todays date which are not exists in previous dates using oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Here is my table :

```
    Id  date         interfaceid
------------------------------
    1   10-12-2015     1502
    2   10-01-2015     1560
    3   10-04-2015     1502
    4   10-03-2015     1502
    5   10-09-2015     1555 
    6   10-12-2015     1569
```

In this data we have to find out the todays(10-12-2015) data which does not exists in previous dates

Comment: select mydata from my_table where mydate = 10-12-2015 minus select mydata from my_table where mydate <> 10-12-2015; change the table and field names to match yours and format the dates correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from yourtable 
where datecol = '10-12-2015'
and value not in(select value from yourtable where datecol <> '10-12-2015')
```

Comment: I tried with the query                                                                            select mydata from my_table  where datetimestamp = to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') minus select mydata  from my_table  where datetimestamp <> CURRENT_DATE;

Comment: @user3829086:- You can give it a try and let me know in case of any issue

Comment: I am getting Following error : ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 2